# What's a good way to differentiate 'reply' buttons for each message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm modifying a Flask MiniTwit example to implement a twitter-like message reply system, where each message has a 'reply' button. I'd like to expand a new div to display replies as well as an input area for when a 'reply' button for a specified message was clicked. But I don't know how to define the 'reply' button in my jinja template.

Currently my code is like the following:

```
<a href=# data-messageid="{{message._id}}" id="reply">
Reply
</a>
```

So how would I differentiate each 'reply' hyperlink button in my jQuery code?

Comment: Do you need to find the data-userid value?

Comment: no, only data-messageid . i'll remove data-userid in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="replymessage" id="message{{message._id}}">content</div>
<a href="#message{{message._id}}" class="reply">Reply</a>


$('.reply').click( function () {
    var item =  $(this).attr('href');
    $(item).slideToggle(300);
 });
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6SvuA/)

Basically you use the dynamic id number in the href of the button, then in the ID for the corresponding div. This way when you click a link with the href, the div with the same ID opens.

Answer (score 3):

Your current template will result in an invalid HTML document (assuming the template is expanded more than once): `id` values **must** be unique in the document, so you can't just have "reply" as the `id`.

I'd probably change "reply" from an `id` to a `class`. Then you can hook them all [directly](http://api.jquery.com/bind):

```
$("a.reply").click(function(event) { ... });
```

...or using [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$("container_for_replies").delegate("a.reply", "click", function(event) { ... });
```

(Using jQuery 1.7 and up, you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate); note that the order of arguments is different.)

Within your event handler, `this` will refer to the specific `a` element that was clicked, so you can (for instance) get your `data-messageid` attribute like this:

```
var messageid = $(this).attr("data-messageid");
```

...and do anything else you like with the structure around the reply link.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since the 'reply' button appear with each message, do not use `id="reply"`. `class="reply"` will be better.

And I think this is what you want:

```
<a href=# data-messageid="1" class="reply">Reply</a>
<a href=# data-messageid="2" class="reply">Reply</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.reply').click(function (argument) {
            alert($(this).attr('data-messageid'));
        });
    });
</script>
```