# Toggle the visibility of multiple div pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code a page which has many "articles".

Each article's title is listed. If the viewer wants to read the article, they click the title.
This causes the div containing the article's text to be displayed.

By default, no article's text should be visible.

I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with the fact that every article title must only toggle it's own text, and not all of the texts, even though they share the same class.

Is it possible to code something like this without manually giving every article text it's own unique ID?

I was thinking I could wrap each article title + text in it's own div. Then have some sort of check that tells it only to show visibility if the div is at the same level (i.e. is in the same div the title is in).

Could someone offer some guidance?

Thanks!

PS: I'd like to stick to a pure html/javascript solution, but I've tagged jquery in case there is an easy way to do it with that solution. I need to avoid PHP because this is not on a server.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388957/whats-a-good-way-to-differentiate-reply-buttons-for-each-message/9389334#9389334

Comment: jQuery can do *much* more than IDs and classes. Post your HTML.

Comment: Post what you have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does indeed make it easy. If your HTML looks like this:

```
<h1>Article 1</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>This is the content of article 1.</p>
</div>
<h1>Article 2</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>This is the content of article 2.</p>
</div>
<h1>Article 3</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>This is the content of article 3.</p>
</div>
```

Then this is all the JavaScript (w/ jQuery) you need:

```
$(".content").hide();
$("h1").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle("fast");
});​
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/tuZAy/) on JSFiddle.**

If you for some reason do not want to use jQuery (because you're not using it for anything else and it's too big to justify for just this, say), you could use plain JavaScript: (**note:** probably only works in newer browsers)

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('content')).forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
});
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'h1') {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = e.target;
    while(content.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE || !/\bcontent\b/.test(content.className)) {
        content = content.nextSibling;
    }
    if(content.style.display === 'none') {
        content.style.display = '';
    }else{
        content.style.display = 'none';
    }
}, false);
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/pLGGb/) on JSFiddle.**

Comment: Thanks! Giving you the right answer because you've provided both a jQuery solution and a plain JS solution. Exactly what I was trying to do. I appreciate the JSFiddle links as well, I did not know about that service.

Comment: I need some help getting the jquery working. I made an extremely simple skeleton file, and you can see the error I'm getting here: http://pastebin.com/EXgEnDUJ It's complaining about the }); of the jquery function.

Any ideas? This is on the latest release of Chromium.

Comment: @user974703: You need an extra `});` to close the `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Comment: sorry somehow that got cutoff from the past, but It is there in my actual file. I double checked and saved again to be sure. Still the same error.

Comment: @user974703: Perhaps try retyping the code without copying and pasting. That error looks like it's saying there's an invalid character somewhere, and you might have copied an invalid character from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Not sure where it happened, but must have been an invisible character somewhere. Once I retyped it I had no problems. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar solution:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6SvuA/)

Essentially you add a bit of dynamic data to the href of a button and the ID of the div containing the content to show.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your HTML:

```
<div class="article">
  <h2>title1</h2>
  <p>article1</p>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <h2>title2</h2>
  <p>article2</p>
</div>
```

And this is your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .article p { display:none; }
</style>
```

This would be a nice jQuery solution:

```
$(function()
{
  $('.article h2').click(function()
  {
    $('p', $(this).parent()).css('display','');
  });
});
```